# Display Discounted Price in the Product view

Tags: magento2

```
<?php
  $priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');
  $finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
  $idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
  $schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
  $valor = $_product->getResource()->getPrice('special_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
  $total = $_product->getFinalPrice();
  $percent = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('desconto')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
  $discount_value = ($total / 100) * $percent;
  $final_price = $total - $discount_value; 
?>
```

Can anybody help me? I'm converting a module from Magento 1 to 2. I put this section to show a price in the product view with a 10% discount in case the customer wants to pay in advance. This value of 10 is taken from a custom product attribute so that when I want to offer 15 I enter the product and make the change. But my codex is giving an error on line 5 Undefined variable. I've already made some changes but none of them worked and I can't display them on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code on top

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article: https://meetanshi.com/blog/display-percentage-of-discount-on-product-list-and-view-page-in-magento-2/